# What are the plug-in chips' caps?

Tags: nier-automata

When I was trying to complete the Speedstar quests, I plugged in all of my movement speed plug-in chips to help my chances of winning. However, I got the notification once I plugged a few in that the cap is +20% for movement speed. Are there other caps for the plug-in chips and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All stackable plug-in chips have hard caps. You won't know these caps until you hit them, but the game will tell you what they are.

I found [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/524220/discussions/0/135512931357094718/) that has all of these caps listed.

> Here are the cap values:
>
> - Weapon Attack Up : +100%
> - Critical Up :+30%
> - Shock Wave :"very powerful"
> - Offensive Heal : 100% of damage dealt as HP
> - Ranged Attack Up : +100%
> - Last Stand : +100% damage if HP is 25% or less
> - Counter : send back 250% damage
> - Charge Attack : +400%
> - Melee Defense : 80%
> - Ranged Defense : 80%
> - Anti Chain Damage : 6 seconds
> - Resilience : avoid stagger if above 5% hp
> - Max HP Up : +100%
> - Deadly Heal : recover 100% hp on kill
> - Auto-Heal : 18%hp/sec after 4sec
> - Damage Absorb : 50% chance to restore 200% of damage taken
> - Reset : 50% chance of reviving with 80% hp
> - Fast Cooldown : 50% cooldown reduction
> - Evade Range Up : +200%
> - Moving Speed Up : +20%
> - Drop Rate Up : +90%
> - EXP Gain Up : +100% exp
> - Vengeance : 50% chance that 200% of damage taken is dealt back
> - Overclock : slow time for 5.5sec after a perfect evade
> - Taunt Up : +500% damage dealt and taken
> - Hijack Boost : +9 level for controlled enemies
> - Stun 25m blast : + 5 seconds stun on a succesful hack
> - Combust : fire for 7 seconds
> - Heal Drops Up : 100% chance to get healing items upon hacking

---

I may be wrong, but based on a few of the fully listed plug-in chip upgrades I'm seeing [on the wiki](http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Plug-in+Chips), it seems like these caps are equivalent to the bonus you would receive from a plug-in chip that has been upgraded to +8.

Answer (score -2):

So far the only 2 caps I know are for:

Drop rate which is at 90%, aka 1 level 8 chip but it's most efficient to use 1 level 4 and 1 level 3 chip

and the EXP gain cap is at 450% witch is 4.5 times the lvl 8 chip.

I found these on the wiki: https://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Plug-in+Chips

I'll do some more research once I'm able to make strong chips.